# Linker errors with glut.h

Tags: opengl, glut, dev-c++

[Linker error] undefined reference to `__glutInitWithExit@12'

[Linker error] undefined reference to `__glutCreateWindowWithExit@8'

[Linker error] undefined reference to `__glutCreateMenuWithExit@8'

[Linker error] undefined reference to `glutSolidSphere@16'

**the problem above came out if i include glut.h header.. why?**

i cant use glutSolidSphere() without it..
 
im using DEV C++ btw..

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/677547/what-does-this-opengl-compilation-error-mean . Please post one question for a given problem.

Comment: Also, please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469150/im-new-to-stackoverflow-what-should-i-consider-before-asking-questions

Comment: voting to close after Kent's update.

Comment: that actually was another question that i change this one just after i got the answer..

Comment: Please mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 1):

The glut.h header just declares the functions. You need to link with the library that implements them, which should be described in the glut documentation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/677547/what-does-this-opengl-compilation-error-mean # Original Question.